# ActiveRecord before_validation callback not fired when called from RSpec example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have read most of the answers pertaining to similar issues but haven't found a solution yet. The code is as follows:

**Setup**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Other inconsequential code
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  before_validation: attach_roles
  # ...
  def attach_roles
    roles << Role.default if roles.blank?
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many: people

  def self.default
  #
  # Get default role
  #
  end

end
```

**Test**

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

describe Person do

  context "constructor" do

    it "creates a valid Person" do
      person = build(:person)
      person.should_receive(:attach_roles) # This works
      person.valid?
      puts person.roles.inspect # Returns []
    end    

    it "creates a another valid Person" do
      person = build(:person)
      person.valid?
      person.should be_valid # This fails
      puts person.roles.inspect # Returns []
    end

  end


end
```

**Problem**

The `attach_roles` callback doesn't seem to be called. However `should_receive` asserts true

**In the console**

```
p = FactoryGirl.build(:person)
p.roles # []
p.valid? # true
p.roles # [<Role>]
```

Would someone be able to explain this please?

*Side note: Any other ideas in trying to achieve creation of a default Role are also welcome.*

**Env**:

- rails **3.2.1**
- ruby **1.9.3**
- rspec **2.12.0**
- factory_girl **4.1.0**

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Is there a specific reason you suggest this? Because just `roles` can be used as an accessor.

Comment: for the same reason `field_name = 'foo'; save` doesn't save 'foo' in the field

Comment: Right. But I'm not concerned about persistence. It seems to work as expected in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Your `should_receive` test proved that `attach_roles` is being called, it's just not doing what you expected.

There are two things I see that concern me.

One is the same thing that @apneadiving pointed out.

When trying to assign to instance variables in Ruby, you must use `self.roles`. What I'm not sure of is how `<< x` works. If it is syntactic sugar for something like `roles= roles + x` then you need `self.roles`, but if it is `roles.insert(x)` then you don't. When in doubt, `self.roles` will always do what you expect.

The other thing that concerns me is that you are using `<<` on a model that has not been persisted. That operation is destructive and will try to persist the `Role`. Since you presumably called the function when you first created the model, this code will only run when it's not persisted. Though I think it mostly works, I'm not sure if that's what you want. I think you would be better off with:

```
def attach_roles
  roles.build(Role.default)
end
```

This assumes that `Role.default` is returning an attributes hash. I may be wrong about what you intended though.

I hope that helps.